# How can I fix the error incorrectly set FixedData property within the TablixRowHierarchy when I deployed my report in SSRS?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix

In my report I have 1 tablix with 1 row group and 1 column group.
When I deployed, my report showed me the following error :

> Warning : The tablix 'Tablix1' has an incorrectly set FixedData property within the TablixRowHierarchy. Only the outermost TablixMembers in a hierarchy can have FixedData set to true.

In my column & row group `-fixedData` is set to true. If I want to set to false, I received the following report : report is invalid. I think the error is not in FixedData, but where?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it.

First click in the Tablix. Then in the Group area, on the right side of the Grouping pane, click the down arrow, and then click **Advanced Mode**.
Then you can check every **Row Groups** and **Column Groups** as well.

It could be that you have in either one of them a not continuous set of *FixedData* in the Porperties.

Here is the full description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-row-and-column-headers-on-multiple-pages-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I had 2 rows for my header and the top row wasn't inside the Row Group. I just realized that's why it wasn't freezing. I added a new one inside the group and now it freezes.